# download image from sql server to local machine using django

Tags: python, sql, django, sql-server-2008, django-models

i have a table in sql server filestorage with columns :

```
storageid: unique identifier
BinaryData: image
```

i need to download this binarydata which will form an image/ppt/etc.. to my local system using django.
How do i do it?

Comment: If you use django ImageField in your model , django saves the image in the file system and its path in the database.

Comment: My database is in different server. and image is stored in that server. if user clicks on download, i should fetch the image from the server and download it in clients system. How do i do it?